# Problem with Unity application passing Windows App Certification Kit tests when referencing Windows Runtime Component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, wack

I have a project in Unity 2018.14.f1. When I export the project as UWP application and build the store package all WACK tests pass fine, but as soon I add a reference to a Windows Runtime Component library, I get the following errors:

The binary analyzer test detected the following errors: 
- File C:\Program Files\windowsapps\26720randomsaladgamesllc.backgammondeluxe_3.4.11.0_x64__kx24dqmazqk8j\clrcompression.dll has failed the AppContainerCheck check.
- File C:\Program Files\windowsapps\26720randomsaladgamesllc.backgammondeluxe_3.4.11.0_x64__kx24dqmazqk8j\clrjit.dll has failed the AppContainerCheck check.

It happens even on plain empty Unity project referencing plain empty library. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I have also asked on Unity forums but didn't get any solution yet https://forum.unity.com/threads/problem-passing-windows-app-certification-kit-tests-when-referencing-runtime-component-library.659221/

Comment: another thing to note is that i'm using IL2CPP scripting

Answer (score 0):

According to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-app-certification-kit-tests

"Make sure that the app was compiled as a release build and not a debug build."

Could be that you're trying to pass the WACK tests with a build built in Debug.

Comment: tried building using both master and release configuration with the same results